# Creating a Dump File for Oracle table

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I intend to export one table from My database as a dmp File. This is what I am doing:

```
expdp SYSTEM/manager@UATDB FILE=F:\LLT.dmp log=F:\llt.log tables=TBAADM.LLT
```

The error I am getting is:

```
 LRM-00101: unknown parameter name 'FILE'
```

What is my mistake. Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Guys I fouund the Answer you need to first Create a Directory where the the dmp File is going to be. Then Import Like this:

```
expdp USERNAME@server ip/SERVICE_NAME 
DIRECTORY=DIR_NAME DUMPFILE=FILE.dmp TABLES=SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

And you can also use

Below one is shell command, so execute this in the shell. Once Data export is completed, the search `dpdump` folder in oracle installed directory where you can find your exported file with log.

```
expdp userid/pwd schemas=dbschema dumpfile=file.dmp logfile=file.log
```